# How to test your Aria tags on your website?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, wai-aria

I been doing some research but I having issues finding a good way to test my Aria-labels, and other Aria tags I used. What is the best practice for testing this. Currently doing this for Angular using Material UI which already has some good ARIA support.

I tried using the trial version of JAWS 9 but sometimes I can't tell if it's my code is bad or the screenreader isn't as good as I hope.

Thanks for reading and hope someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 7):

Chrome devtools has build in accessibility check:

1. Press F12 (or just open your Chrome devtools)
2. Choose the tab "Elements"
3. Click on the tag you want to inspect
4. there has a part underneath where you can see all the styles for your tags, classes,...and it is calles "Styles"
   here you can also choose between tabs, so choose then for "accessibility"
5. Now you are able to see which aria attributes are set for your tag.
   (In this image you can see that I put an aria-hidden attribute on my font-awesome so screenreaders don't try to read the icon)

[image: image of an example how the accessibility tab looks like]

Answer (score 6):

[JAWS](https://support.freedomscientific.com/Downloads/JAWS) has been around for a long time so if things are not working like you'd expect, sorry to say, it's probably a problem with your code.  However, JAWS isn't great for testing because the intent of JAWS is to allow visually impaired users to get stuff done on their computer.  JAWS uses some heuristics when it's reading a website and if you have bad html, JAWS will try to figure out what you meant so that the end user can finish their task.

[NVDA](https://www.nvaccess.org/download/) is a great a screen reader for testing.  It will not try to guess what your code is doing and if you have poorly written html, it'll be read poorly.  And it's free (although donations appreciated).

Both JAWS and NVDA are for the PC.

On a Mac, you can use the built in [VoiceOver](https://help.apple.com/voiceover/mac/10.14/) screen reader.  Nothing to install.  Just hit <kbd>Cmd+F5</kbd>.

Turn the screen reader on and navigate through your site using <kbd>tab</kbd> and listen for how interactive elements are announced.  You can turn on NVDA's speech viewer tool (ins+n > tools > speech viewer) and you can see what is being spoken.  VoiceOver has a "closed captions" type viewer so you can see what's being announced.  Your aria-labels will be read by the screen reader.

You can also use the shortcut keys when NVDA is running to see if other elements are defined properly.

- H - navigate to the next heading
- B - navigate to the next button
- T - navigate to the next table
- L - navigate to the next list

See https://www.nvaccess.org/files/nvda/documentation/userGuide.html#SingleLetterNavigation

Comment: warn your colleagues you will become very irritable once you start testing with a screen reader!

Comment: totally false.  using a screen reader can be very liberating.

Comment: I’m sure jaws has better functionality than nvda and that’s what I’m using. It’s driving me insane. The question is about testing a website which I have to assume is at the development phase. The screen reader will of course continuously read everything including when you switch to other tabs / your IDE / your email. That’s what I’m referring to. A complex website will take many many days to get running properly in a screen reader and you’ll have to continuously listen over and over to the thing reading out everything.

Comment: Of course if you’re visually impaired it can be liberating using such tools if the site is well designed but during development I don’t see how the word liberating can possibly apply!

Comment: The problem is that my "liberating" comment and your "irritable" comment are both subjective.  Sure, it might be irritating to you but to make a general statement that it'll be irritating to everyone is false.  I use NVDA, JAWS, and VoiceOver.  Hearing things in many different apps (browser, email, IDE) gives you a sense for what it's like to use just your hearing instead of your eyes to navigate around your computer.  By default, NVDA has mouse tracking turned on, which I agree can be overkill. It's the first thing I turn off.  Perhaps that will help you.

Answer (score 2):

[Chromevox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromevox/kgejglhpjiefppelpmljglcjbhoiplfn/related) is a good plugin for simulating screen reader if that's what you are looking for. If you're interested in learning how good your website is conforming to accessibility guidelines, you can go to the audits in chrome dev tools & run a report. (Ctrl+ Shift + I -->Audits --> Select only accessibility & hit Run audits)

[image]